# Facebook iOS SDK : publish in background

Tags: ios, facebook

I can’t find (and I wonder if it is still possible) in the lastest FB SDK how to achieve background publishing. 
The publish permissions are all gone (FBLoginButton or GraphAPI), I can’t find a single updated piece of code). It seems that it is no longer possible and new apps have to rely on the ShareKit that présent à dialog.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that’s pretty much it. Posting without requiring this kind of user interaction, just lead to too much spam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about user profile publishing: The required permission `publish_actions` is not available anymore, there is no way to publish to user profiles with the API anymore. You must use share dialogs.

Comment: Thanks guys, that’s what I was afraid of. 
However, correct me if I’m wrong, but I still can publish in background for pages when the user who is logged in is an administrator of the page right?

Comment: exactly, with a page token of that page

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I'm not so dumb after all :D :D Do you know if it works the same for Instagram feed? Is there a way with the new SDK to publish in background ? Thanks again luschn ;-)

Comment: afaik instagram never had an api to publish, so i assume there is no way with the new api.